# onTap not working on Polygons / Google Maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I'm using google_maps_flutter(https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package.

Widget structure is  `Scaffold > Stack > GoogleMap`

The problem is that Markers' onTap events works fine but Polygons' onTap events don't fire at all.

Why is this?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could take a look at the issue?

Comment: Showing the code it matters a lot so as you can easily be helped.

Answer (score 6):

Make `consumeTapEvents: true`, which is an attribute of Polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and setting an empty onTap method for the GoogleMap object made it work

```
GoogleMap(
   ... 
   onTap: (x) {},
)
```